# Analytics API Throwing Exception After 2 years Working Without Issue

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have attempted to use a piece of code I've used every week for two years today to generate reports from the Analytics API. It is suddenly throwing an exception, with no change to the code having occurred, this is the exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'GAPI: Failed to authenticate user. Error: "https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps "' in /var/www/reporting/internal/gapi.class.php:418 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/reporting/internal/gapi.class.php(62): gapi->authenticateUser('...', '...') #1 /var/www/reporting/internal/add_report.php(299): gapi->__construct('...', '...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/reporting/internal/gapi.class.php on line 418

I haven't changed my account password. It's obviously not authenticating, but I can't see any reason *why*.

Anyone have any ideas? I did some Googling around the subject but can't see anything specific to my query – the main issue I have is that I've changed nothing my end.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It certainly seems similar @DaImTo, but it appears that GAPI was shut down in April and yet my code has been working since.

I will obviously have to re-write it at some point to run through Service, but if there's a quick bodge for now that'd be very useful!

Comment: That's because its a rolling shutdown.  Not all the APIs where shut down at once.   A huge number where shutdown yesterday.  Google Analytics was one of them.   There is no bodge you cant access Google APIs with client login.  the authentication end point has been turned off.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @DaImTo, I will switch over to a service account login as soon as possible.

Comment: http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/  that should help